# Hibernate and JPA annotations - persist a list of phrases

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm having trouble using hibernate to persist a simple java object containing just a list of phrases in the form of strings.
To store this in a MySql database I have two tables:

**phrase_list - columns:
 group_id,  phrase_id, list_position**  (which together make up the primary key; also there is a foreign key constraint on phrase_id from the phrase table)

**phrase - columns: phrase_id, phrase** (phrase is a varchar with a unique index)

I would like to simply be able to annotate the object containing the list of phrases in order to persist it, but nothing I've tried has worked, I've tried examples and variations of using @ElementCollection and @OneToMany with another Entity representing the phrase, but no matter what I try I can't seem to get this to work.

For example a phrase list: {"a","b","b"} would be stored as:

```
**(phrase table)**      **(phrase_list table)**
phrase_id  phrase       group_id  phrase_id  list_position
   1       'a'            1           1           0
   2       'b'            1           2           1
                          1           2           2
```

Here is the attempt to what I thought would work; I added an extra id field because I could see no way to use the foreign key as part of the id, and annotating the list with @Id didn't work.

```
@Entity @Table(name = "phrase_list")
public class PhraseList {

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
          name="phrase",
          joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="phrase_id")
    )
    @OrderColumn(name="list_position")
    @Column(name="phrase")
    private List<String> phrases;

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "list_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "goup_id")
    private Long groupId;

    public void setResults(List<String> results){
        this.results = results;
    }

    public void setGroupId(Integer groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }
}
```

I get this exception:

> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
>   ERROR: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (test_db`.`phrase_list`, CONSTRAINT`fk_phrase_list_phrase_id`FOREIGN KEY (`phrase_id`) REFERENCES`phrase`(`phrase_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE )

Is there any way to get this to work simply by annotating the plain Java object?  If not what is the best way to achieve this?

If I can't get it to work with annotation I would probably write custom queries and/or specialized methods for persisting the object.  I.e., a method that is coupled to that particular class in knowing how to persist its objects, which I hoped to avoid.

Comment: I assume you shouldn't hassle with all those ids. Check out [this example](http://antoniogoncalves.org/2009/11/01/mapping-and-querying-a-list-of-primitive-types-with-jpa-2-0/) which also uses a list of simple types.

Comment: Thanks, the example isn't quite what I'm looking for but helped me realize why what I was doing is not working.  I want to make the list from a unique set of phrases (to prevent 2 million phrases being  re-dded every time the application runs  which would mostly be duplicates - instead it would be two million rows mapping to a relatively fixed set of a couple hundred thousand phrases via their ids).